# Animations suddenly not working at all

Tags: animation, godot

I have three animations, "ShowHit", "WarningFadeInAndOut", "ShowGameOver". They were worked when I was made, but suddenly only "ShowHit" is working. I double checked the logic was correct so that it executes to play animation and there's no problem with my code, but even played animations, just nothing changed in my screen.

I do nothing about animation stuffs, but why it suddenly doesn't work? If I go to animation tab and hit play, it works, but in game, animation just not working at all.

Also in "ShowGameOver" animation, I animated modulate value which was 0 to 1, so make it appears to the screen. However Sometimes when I set the modulate's alpha value to 1.0, I can't see it. Of course visible is checked.

Is all these are just bug or glitch? Why suddenly my animations just not working? Any advice? Using Godot 3.1.1.

Comment: I have no idea, but give little delay before animation_player.play will trigger animation well, still WarningFadeInAndOut animation doesn't play.

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is not enough information here to tell what the issue is.